# Function parameters causing promise resolve error

Tags: javascript, json, angular, promise

I have a function (`buildOrganization`) that updates my graph in the UI.

It works with the exact same structure of data as I am now trying to put through it (data it works with is `updatedGraphTable`)

Trying to use it as I am for a second time throws an error (in function `getSubsidiaryEngagements`)

> TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings

Both sets of data are received after calling an endpoint and are a JSON response -  array of objects format. `{ {[  {[    ]}  ]} }` like such.

Here is my code:

Function to update code (graph file):

```
 buildOrganization(root, resolve): void {
  if (root) {
    this.organization.clear();
    this.organization.setProperties(root, this.filterParams);
    this.focus = this.organization;
    if (this.userList.length === 0) {
      this.userList = this.organization.individuals;
    }
    this.reload = false;
    this.data();
    resolve(true);
  }
}
```

Using the function with it working (passing `updatedGraphTable` through it - which has the same structure of data as my other data - array of objects. (they are derived from the same endpoint):

```
graph(id: string): Promise < boolean > {
  if (this.organization.id && this.organization.id !== id) {
    this.organization = new EngagementRoot();
    this.resetGraph();
  }
  this.organization.setValues(id);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!this.reload) {
      resolve(false);
    } else {
      let areasLoaded = false;
      let root: IEngagementGraphNode;

      Observable.zip(this.organizationEngagements(id, this.requestOptions()), this.organizationIndividuals(id, this.requestOptions()))
        .subscribe(([updatedGraphTable, individualsData]) => {
          if (areasLoaded) {
            console.log('updated graph table!' + JSON.stringify(updatedGraphTable))
            return this.buildOrganization(updatedGraphTable, resolve);

          } else {
            root = updatedGraphTable;
          }
        }, error => reject(error));
    }
  });
}
```

Now this is the function that isn't working, I'm including it outside of this graph function as I only want it called when I invoke it from another file which I will show (so the data is entering in the same way `updatedGraphTable` was:

```
getSubsidiaryEngagements(subId, resolve) {
  return this.subsidiariesEngagements(subId)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log('subsidiary engagements' + JSON.stringify(data));

      return this.buildOrganization(data, resolve); < --error!
    })
}
```

Then in my other file I'm trying to call this new function:

```
updateSub(data) {
  this.engagementService.getSubsidiaryEngagements(this.subId, resolve)
}
```

But before I even get to call it i get this error in the console as the page first loads up, before i even call the function but it also shows when i call it:

> TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
>           at webpackJsonp.../../../../path-browserify/index.js.exports.resolve

I'm sure I'm being silly and missing something obvious?

Comment: in `updateSub` - what is `resolve`? where is it declared?

Comment: It's nothing you are right, although my error is actually thrown before I ever call updateSub

Comment: So I think resolve in getSubsidiaryEngagements isn't declared anywhere either now i think about it

Comment: yes it is, it's passed in as the second argument ... it comes from `new Promise((resolve, reject)` ... but in updateSub it seems to be something else

Comment: Are you sure? I never call getSubsidiaryEngagements within the graph function which has the new Promise, it's outside of it

Comment: I can't tell you where the problem is. But you use Promises in a wrong way. You should never pass those `resolve`  and `reject`  functions around in such a way, this creates messy connections that are hard to debug and is an anti-pattern. If `buildOrganization` is really async or expected to be async in future, then `buildOrganization` should return an own Promise from it. So it should be `buildOrganization(root): Promise <boolean> { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... resolve(true); ... })}`.

Comment: Sorry @JaromandaX you were correct, how would i parse a resolve into updateSub?

Comment: Like you do elsewhere